# Eigenvalue of Hamiltonian under gauge transform of Bloch state

Tags: condensed-matter, gauge

$H = \sum_{k} V(q) a_{k4}^{\dagger}b_{k3}^{\dagger}b_{k2}a_{k1}$

where $q$ is the transfer momentum, $a$ $b$ are two orbits or two sublattice sites.

Will the eigenvalues of the above Hamiltonian *unchanged* under the following transform (gauge transform of Bloch state):

$b_k \to e^{i\theta(k)}b_k$     where $\theta(k)$ is real

Comment: Are the number indices such of the momenta, i.e. $k_1, k_2, \ldots$ or such of the operators $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I just short some notation to make the question clear, here is the full one: $\sum_k := \sum_{k_4, k_3, k_2, k_1} \delta_{k_4+k_3,k_2+k_1}$, and  $q=k_4-k_1$

Answer (score 0):

The interaction term is not invariant under the gauge transformation. $b_k\rightarrow e^{i\theta_k}b_k$ is only a symmetry for the non-interacting Hamiltonian $H=\sum_k E(k)b_k^\dagger b_k$.

Comment: The term itself is not invariant, but the physics is invariant. Like electrons under magnetic field, different vector potential will change the Hamiltonian but not the physics.

Comment: My understanding is that different gauge are different mathematical description of the same physics problem. So the eigenvalue should not changed.

Comment: Or say this gauge transform is just an unitary transform on the original Hamiltonian.

Comment: The physics is invariant under local gauge transformation in real space, provided you include U(1) gauge fields. Notice that the Hamiltonian of electrons in a magnetic field is actually invariant once you take into account the gauge transformations on the electron operators and the vector potential, otherwise it would not be called a symmetry.

Comment: I agree the Hamiltonian is invariant. I think I mean the "form of the Hamiltonian" written in the new field operator changed.